# R: Clock syncs - Stepwise repetition of calculation applied to all records

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to synchronize data from two clocks. Each clock is drifting at different rates. I'd like to synchronize simultaneous events detected on both instruments to the clock of one instrument. Here are some simple data where the times are numeric representing minutes from some starting point:

```
MasterClock <- c(100, 150, 200, 250, 300)
clock2 <- c(101, 153, 206, 258, 310)
df <- data.frame(MasterClock,clock2)
```

The first step is simple. Identify a simultaneous event and calculate the difference in time between the two clocks and adjust one clock accordingly. I want to keep a record of the difference between the clocks so I will create a new variable of the difference between the clocks, then add the difference to the original time to get a corrected time, like this:

```
df$CF[1] <- df$MasterClock[1] - df$clock2[1] #calculate CorrectionFactor
df$clock2Corrected <- df$clock2 + df$CF  #calculate corrected time
```

giving this:

```
 > df
  MasterClock clock2 CF clock2Corrected
1         100    101 -1             100
2         150    153 -1             152
3         200    206 -1             205
4         250    258 -1             257
5         300    310 -1             309
```

In this simplified example, it is easy to see that each row represents one simultaneous event. However, if you were to continue the trend in clock2, eventually clock2 will drift so far that it will begin to look like it occurred simultaneously with the previous event on the master clock. This is why I want to apply the correction factor from the first record to all of the data first, syncing the clocks every chance I get to keep the clocks as tight as possible (the real data set is obviously much larger and more complex, increasing the likelihood of an assignment error).

From here I need to repeat this process using df$clock2Corrected[2] as the new "original time" for clock 2. The CorrectionFactor (CF) for the second record would be df$MasterClock[2] - df$clock2Corrected[2] = -2. I would then want to apply this correction factor (-2) to records 2-n to get the new updated synced clock for records 2-n. Doing this stepwise will keep the clocks tight so that the CF should remain small over time.

Is there a way to repeat this process step-wise for each record without creating a new column for every row? I suspect it may need to be a forloop nested inside of another forloop but I can't wrap my head around the logic. Here's what I'd like the finish product to be in the end for this example:

```
> df
  MasterClock clock2 CF clock2Corrected
1         100    101 -1             100
2         150    153 -2             150
3         200    206 -3             200
4         250    258 -2             250
5         300    310 -2             300
```

Comment: @RuiBarradas Apply the cumulative correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it took a while but I think I've got it.

```
correct_clock <- function(DF){
    DF$CF <- DF$MasterClock[1] - DF$clock2[1]
    DF$clock2Corrected <- DF$clock2 + DF$CF
    n <- nrow(DF)
    for(i in seq_len(n)[-1]){
        DF$CF[i] <- DF$MasterClock[i] - DF$clock2Corrected[i]
        DF$clock2Corrected[i:n] <- DF$clock2[i:n] + sum(DF$CF[1:i])
    }
    DF
}

correct_clock(df)
  MasterClock clock2 CF clock2Corrected
1         100    101 -1             100
2         150    153 -2             150
3         200    206 -3             200
4         250    258 -2             250
5         300    310 -2             300
```

You must then assign the return value of function `correct_clock` to some data frame, the same or other.

```
result <- correct_clock(df)
```